# Why can't I load this class file in Rhino console?

Tags: java, classpath, rhino

I'm prototyping a web page scraper using Rhino and Env-js. Nevermind that the documentation for both projects is atrocious... I'm trying to load up the File.java example class that is supplied with Rhino. For simplicity sake, I've got File.java, js.jar, jline.jar and env.rhino.1.2.js all in one directory. I've tried specifying the current directory using the classpath command line option, but still whenever I call `defineClass("File")` I get an error saying the class file isn't found. What am I doing wrong here??

```
$ ls -1
File.java
env.rhino.1.2.js
jline.jar
js.jar
$ java -cp .:js.jar:jline.jar jline.ConsoleRunner org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main -opt -1
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2009 03 22
js> defineClass("File")
js: "<stdin>", line 2: Class "File" not found.
    at <stdin>:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to compile File.java before using it, as the classpath "." only makes sense if it contains some compiled class in it?

Comment: If that's the case then it is not mentioned anywhere in the Rhino documentation. And why wouldn't they just ship the examples already compiled? Sorry, rhetorical questions. Anyway, so how would I compile them? Sorry, I spend most of my time in scripting languages, not compiled ones.